# Homography for Image Rectification

Tags: computer-vision, homography

We can do image rectification given stereo images. For a single image we can find the two vanishing points and then the vanishing line. Using this vanishing line we can do projective rectification. But what constraints are required for affine rectification??

I basically want to rectify an image to its frontal view such that parallel line in the world are parallel and also parallel to the x-axis. I hope am making myself clear ..

Also what is the homography to transfer a vanishing point (x,y) in the image to (1,0,0) ???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

A projective transformation transfers an imaged point to an ideal point (1,0,0). It thereby rectifies an image up to an affine transformation of what people would normally want to see. This process is "affine rectification". Affine transformations keep lines parallel, but can skew the image and make it look weird, so I'm not sure if that's where you want to stop. Affine transformations can turn circles into ellipses and can change the angle of intersecting lines.

To remove the affine transformation (metric rectification), one must identify the "conic dual to the circular points". This can be done by identifying two pairs of perpendicular lines; identifying an ellipse that should really be a circle; or by using two known length ratios. Once this is done, the only differences between your image and how you would like it to look will be its scale, its x and y positions and the rotation of the whole image.

Comment: if you transfer " imaged point to an ideal point (1,0,0)" that is to Inf. this would introduce infinite scaling of the image. You probably meant an epipolar point, not image point.